# Although user is logged in, why does Artifactory ask for a credential again after clicking on "url to file" of the artifact?

Tags: single-sign-on, artifactory, saml

When a user clicks on "URL to file" on Artifactory, although he is logged in, Artifactory again asks for the credential and user must provide that.
Is there any solution to skip this when user already logged in?
In our case we are using SSO and user does not have specific credential for Artifactory. Due to the security concerns we cannot allow anonymous access so this is not the desired solution for this problem.

I read the Artifactory documentation but I could not find a proper solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we should change `artifactory.redirect.native.browser.requests.to.ui` to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Artifactory version is 7.x, it is expected behaviour. The reason is that the Artifactory UI is accessed as "https://myartifactory.com/ui" here the "/ui" context holds the user credential cookie and the context changes from "/ui" to "/artifactory" when the user clicks on "URL to file" therefore the credential cookie is not shared from "/ui" to "/artifactory".

This Native UI is included in [version 7.21.3](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Release+Notes#:%7E:text=Native%20Artifacts%20Browser%20Accessible%20from%20the%20UI), if the Artifactory version is lower than 7.21.3, an upgrade would help.

Comment: so there is no solution to address the issue? we want that users will be able to use the link without providing credentials again and again.

Comment: Can you please tell me the current Artifactory version

Comment: our version is 7.46